# Wien bridge oscillator circuit doesn't work

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator, troubleshooting, sine, wien-bridge

I've connected the circuit of Fig 3.4.6 in [this link](http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/Oscillators/osc34.php) which is shown below:

[image]

Here is the circuit that I've connected:

[image]

Where in my circuit:

- R3 = 100 kOhm
- R4 = 47 kOhm
- R1 = R2 = 5.1 kOhm
- C1 = C2 = 100 nF
- Op amp is of type 741
- Diodes are of type [1N4001](http://www.diodes.com/_files/datasheets/ds28002.pdf)

I chose R3 and R4 based on this circuit from [here](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/oscillator/wien_bridge.html):

[image]

This circuit is the same as the one in the first figure except that there are no diodes.

When I connected the output of the circuit to an oscilloscope, here is all what I could see:

[image]

I tried connecting a potentiometer in place of R4 and varying its value but with no noticeable changes in the output.

Note: I've simulated my circuit using Multisim but using different diode types (1N4148), and the results were good.

How can I get the circuit to operate properly?

Comment: I think you need to get your multimeter out and check the values of those resistors. The yellow-blue-brown-gold resistor looks out of place to me.

Comment: No. It's a 47 kOhm resistor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using your op amp in a single-supply configuration without providing a virtual ground. The simplest fix is to get another 14 volt supply, and connect this as a negative supply to pin 4. If you're not willing to do this, try

[image: schematic]

Your output will now have an offset of about 7 volts, which may or may not be a problem, especially since any noise on the 14 volt line will (except for the filtering provided by C1) show up on the output as well. This is why I say it's easier to provide a second power supply. YMMV, of course.

Also, make sure to provide a 0.1 uF ceramic cap between V+ and ground for each op amp. Connect the cap right next to the pins of each IC - don't use jumpers.

Comment: There are simpler solutions (one opamp only) for single supply oscillators. Try googling - and you will find the circuits, for example:http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/AN-111.pdf

Comment: Thank you. I connected the negative supply today in the lab and the circuit worked well. But maybe I need some adjustments. I may ask about them in different questions.

Comment: @ammarx - Any time. We live to serve. In the future, though, learn to use the schematic entry option (the icon that inludes a diode, 7th from the left when you open a question or answer window, or simply hitting ctrl-m). It's much clearer than a picture of your breadboard.